# Favicon not showing up when adding an article or blog post to Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, jobs, favicon

I'm clicking "add an article or blog post you’ve written" on my Careers profile, and adding a URL such as:

http://www.websightdesigns.com/posts/view/how-to-set-up-a-local-web-server-with-homebrew-on-mac-os-x-10-9

However, after I click "Get Article" I see a broken image for the icon.

When I inspect the element of this broken image, it shows the following code:

```
<img alt="" class="favicon" src="http://www.websightdesigns.com/posts/view/how-to-set-up-a-local-web-server-with-homebrew-on-mac-os-x-10-9/favicon.ico">
```

Here are the entire contents of the document's `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="How to use Vagrant to configure a Linux web server virtual machine running Apache, MySQL and PHP on Ubuntu Precise.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web design, web hosting, computers, servers, mobile web, programming, technology">
    <meta name="author" content="webSIGHTdesigns.com <www.websightdesigns.com>">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.websightdesigns.com/posts/view/how-to-configure-an-ubuntu-web-server-vm-with-vagrant">
    <meta property="og:title" content="How to Configure an Ubuntu Web Server VM with Vagrant">
    <meta property="og:description" content="How to Configure an Ubuntu Web Server VM with Vagrant - webSIGHTdesigns">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="webSIGHTdesigns.com">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.websightdesigns.com/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_us">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="jkhAzT3Rl30yPcXYVeTnAU-D2j19YJDrak_8HZ6eYjM">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>How to Configure an Ubuntu Web Server VM with Vagrant - webSIGHTdesigns</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/js/vendor/prism.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/js/vendor/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/img/ico/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.websightdesigns.com/">
</head>
```

As you can see, the only line in the `<head>` tag that mentions favicon.ico is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Am I missing something, or this an bug in Careers Profiles?

I typically don't have any issues showing the favicon when posting articles to Facebook, for example.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. This *is* a legitimate bug. We weren't properly handling absolute favicon URLs. Should be all patched up now - try adding the article again. Let us know if you continue experiencing unexpected behavior.

Comment: Are you sure this is working? I've added some blog posts to my CV and no favicon is showing. My problem is the same. The broken URL is http://zanon.io/posts/building-serverless-websites-on-aws-tutorial/favicon.ico  It should look for http://zanon.io/favicon.ico instead.

Comment: This feature works for me in Chrome. If it is not working for you, please provide the details in a new post, including browser version, OS, exact URL of the page causing the problem, and exact URL of the blog URL.

Comment: It's working now! I've changed my favicon path from "/favicon.ico" to "zanon.io/favicon.ico" and removed/added again and worked. Ty!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Zanon !